# WebStorm IDE support for Vue 3 Composition API really bad or is my config messed up?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ide, webstorm

With **Vue 2** I had no issues and I think the **WebStorm Plugin** is really **first class** - I even think it works better OOTB than on VS Code.

But I have started multiple **Vue 3** based projects using the **Composition API** and it seems that the **WebStorm Vue plugin is just not ready yet?!**

Using `<script setup>` is pretty much unusable. And when using `setup() {}` method I get a bunch of weird typing errors and warnings.

I don't really find a lot of information about this online, so I am starting to think that maybe my config is screwed up?!

I bootstrapped a **fresh Vue 3** app using the **Vue CLI** and **reinstalled WebStorm** making sure all previous settings get **reset to default.**

**Same result.**

Really curious to get some feedback from fellow developers about their experience with WebStorm and Vue 3 Composition API.

Comment: If you are having issues with Vue 3 support in WebStorm then I would suggest to contact JetBrains Support directly (`WebStorm Main Menu | Help | Contact Support...`) where you can privately provide some sample code/exact issues etc

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am more looking for others to share their experience and and get a better understanding of the current implications. I opened an issue on their Issue Tracker website - but no engagement for weeks now. Will try the "Contact Support" option but I think it just creates another issue.

Comment: I have problems with PHPStorm 2021+ and vue3 SFCs. PS gives me a lot of false hints, warnings and even errors like "unreachable code", "unused function/constant/...", "unnecessary semicolon" and more. It seems there are some issues with the "intellisense" or whatever it is called. I also notice a steady memory allocation from 1000 to 2000. It drops back to 1000 and begins again.

Answer (score 2):

The new `<script setup>`is not yet supported, work is in progress; the fix can likely be expected in 2021.2, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49000#focus=Comments-27-4909862.0-0

For other problems you have faced, please feel free to contact the support directly as advised by @LazyOne